# Showing that $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) > \alpha \Rightarrow f(c+h) > \alpha$ for $|h| < \delta $ where $\delta > 0 $

Tags: limits, continuity, proof-writing, formal-proofs

The question is as follows :

> Let f : (a,b) $\to \mathbb{R}$ and c $\epsilon$ (a,b) be such that $\lim_{x\to c}  f(x) > \alpha$. Prove that there exists some $\delta > 0 $ such that $f(c+h) >\alpha $ for all $|h| < \delta $

I have taken a rather lengthy approach of splitting it into 9 different cases as follows, but I am happy about my method.

Case 1 : monotonically increasing
Case 2 : monotonically decreasing
Case 3 : constant function
Case 4 : x is a point of minima
Case 5 : x is a point of maxima
Case 6 : constant function to the left of x = c and increasing to the right of x = c
Case 7 : constant function to the right of x = c and increasing to the left of x = c
Case 8 : constant function to the left of x = c and decreasing to the right of x = c 
Case 9 : constant function to the right of x = c and decreasing to the left of x = c

I have managed to prove all cases but case 5 with ease.

I am unsure of how to proceed with a formal proof of case 5.
For all other cases I have used the basic definitions of increasing/decreasing/constant.

Can someone guide me how to proceed with proof of case 5 ?

Comment: Your cases are not exhaustive. Regardless, there is no need to consider different cases; just use the definition of limit. Start by taking  $\epsilon=L-\alpha$, where $L$ is the value of your limit.

Comment: Also, you need $h$ non-zero here...

Comment: Amazing !! A huge shout out to you @DavidMitra. Thanks you so much ! I was thinking what to do with the gap between f(c) and alpha and you're like take $\epsilon = L - \alpha$. Too good !

Comment: @DavidMitra why are my cases not exhaustive though ?

Comment: Look at $y=x\sin(1/x)$ around $0$ (the function has "infinite oscillation" about 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By limit definition $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0, |x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. By hypothesis, we are given $L>\alpha$.

$L-\epsilon<f(x)<L+\epsilon$, rewriting the limit definition as a compound inequality.

So:

$L-\epsilon-\alpha<f(x)-\alpha<L+\epsilon-\alpha$.

Select $\epsilon<L-\alpha$. Then we guarantee $f(x)-\alpha>0$ for some $\delta$ and $c-\delta<x<c+\delta$ by the earlier statements. This inequality still holds for $c-h<x<c+h, |h|<\delta$ since it overlaps.